# In C++ can you return the contents of a stack as a string using a ToString() function?

Tags: c++, stack, tostring

I think my tutor is getting mixed up with Java and C# because I can't find any information online about how to do this in C++.

The exercise he gave is:

> Write a generic (templated) stack abstract data type (ADT) class and return the contents of the stack as a string using the following function: ToString()

Comment: What is your tutor asking you to do? Give some more context.

Comment: Write a generic (templated) stack abstract data type (ADT) class  and return the contents of the stack as a string using the following function: ToString()

Comment: Your tutor is asking you to implement this ToString function yourself. You need to clarify with your tutor what is wanted, because it isn't obvious how to stringify an arbitrary class.

Answer (score 0):

> In C++ can you return the contents of a stack as a string using a ToString() function?

If you write a function named `ToString` that accepts a stack object as an argument and returns a string that represents the contents of the stack object then yes, you can use the function you wrote. From the context, I would guess that your tutor is asking you to write the function.